# spring: order a list of spring beans based on getOrder method

Tags: spring

I have a base class which is extended by a lot of model classes that are spring beans(`@Component`), my base class implement `Ordered` interface and implement method `getOrder()`.
When I inject in class the hole list of spring beans(`List<? extend BaseClass> springBeans`) I want to be ordered based on `getOrder` implementation but this method it's not called ever when the beans are created.

Why isn't the `getOrder` method called ?

Answer (score 0):

I find the cause, base class should implement BeanPostProcessor interface, now getOrder method is called.

Comment: That shouldn't be needed to have this method called, a `BeanPostProcessor` is a specific type of bean. If the method isn't called there is something else wrong in your setup.

Comment: hmmm .. seams everything it's ok, even my seams strange to implement bean as a PostProcessor in order to can be call getOrder method

Comment: I doubt everything is ok... A `BeanPostProcessor` has nothing to do with `Ordered` and is, besided that, a special type of bean for a very special purpose. You shouldn't just implement it because it appears to fix your problem.

Comment: from what i see in spring frmaework the oreder of list of spring beans all of base type is make in OrderComparator class. In AbstractApplicationContext class is call OrderComparartor.sort(postPorcessorBeans) .. so that was the reason to be a PostProcessor. I create a simple application with 3 beans ans inject them as a list, I want that list to be ordered by getOrder method, but it's not called if the spring bean is not a postProcessor.

Comment: As that issue states implementing the interface to order the list is a work around. It should work out-of-the-box. (At least in the 4.0 spring version) if it doesn't there is something wrong in your setup...

Comment: yes, with v4.0 it's working out-of-the-box, anyway with v3.0 isn't work. Thanks for your help.